# C++ Find string of string in list<string>variable name

Tags: c++, list

In my declaration, I make a list as follow

```
list<string> abc;
```

and I have saved something in it.

and now I want to do a keyword search.

```
int counter = 0;
list<string>::iterator it;
key = "something"

for (it = abc.begin(); it != abc.end(); it++){
    if(*it.find(key) != std::string::npos)
        counter++;
}
```

and now it gives an error "**no member named 'find' in std::_1::_list_iterator, void*>'; did you mean to use -> instead of .?**"

So I changed `if(*it->find(key) != std::string::npos)`
and it gives an error too
"**indirection requires pointer operand('size_type'(aka 'unsigned long') invalid)**"

Do anyone know what is the problem?

Also I have tried to cout the type of the list
"`cout << type of (*it)`" 
but it also comes out an error...

Comment: question poorly formatted

Comment: Hint: `*it.find(key)` will be parsed as `*(it.find(key))`

Comment: Regarding `cout << type of (*it)`, instead of that you can include the `<typeinfo>` header and write `cout << typeid(*it).name()`. But it's up to the compiler how to present that information. Visual C++ gives you a nice normal type specification, while g++ by default gives you a silly cryptic mangled thing. Goodness knows what they thought that could be useful for. With a lot of extra work you can use some g++-specific functionality to fix its result. Possibly you can find a recipe here on SO.

Comment: Are you simply trying to find a string in your list container?  If so, then why not just use `std::find`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No they're trying to find a substring in any of the strings in the list.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie Yes, I just want to find a substring in a string which is stored in list container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to **first** dereference the iterator and **then** call `find`:

```
if(it->find(key) != std::string::npos)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if((*it).find(key) != std::string::npos)
```

---

What you wrote first, `*it.find(key)`, will be parsed by the compiler as `*(it.find(key))`, i.e. first call `find` on `it` and then dereference the result.

What you tried after that, `*it->find(key)`, will be similarly parsed as `*(it->find(key))`, i.e. first dereference `it`, then call `find` on the result, and finally dereference the result of `find`.

None of them does what you wanted.

To remember:

- `a->b` = `(*a).b`
- `*a.b` = `*(a.b)`

Comment: Could you tell me more about the concept

Comment: How about if I want to search multiple keywords? What is the best way?

Comment: I have decided 
if(it->find(key) != std::string::npos || it->find(key2) != std::string::npos || it->find(key3) != std::string::npos)

Comment: Would there any quick or efficient methods?

Comment: That seems okay if the strings are not super long.

Comment: Not super long, but maybe the number of keyword is large, like 50-60